# Changing AD password - When is it applied

Tags: passwords, policy

I need to change the password of a user who will be relieved from his job.
So my question is, if I change the password on the AD and his computer goes to sleep will it require the new password when unlocking or is a reboot necessary ?
It's an SBS2011 and the computer a Win10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will require the new password at unlocking. But you can test it also.